# Is it possible to implement one-click Facebook login with Ionic?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, ionic-framework, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

Right now, the Facebook login I have implemented in the Ionic app asks for the user to type in email address and password manually instead of using user's FB authentication details from either the FB app or the phone's FB setting.

I'd like the login system to not ask the user to manually type in their email address and password, and will use the FB authentication inside the phone instead.

I'd like to do this in both Android and iOS if possible. If not then one is better then none.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Facebook Connect plugin, this plugin is also available for ngCordova. I've used it and it works fine. In case you have Facebook app already installed on your iOS/Android device it will use that app to log in the user automatically.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/